# panic: Get "https://{addr}/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/secrets/kubernetes-dashboard-csrf": x509: certificate is valid for {ips,} not {addr}

Tags: minikube, kubernetes-dashboard

I think I followed the tutorial from docker, minikube to create kube cluster, it was working at first time. But after somedays, I restart cluster and got this error when starting dashboard. Restart doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try to perform `minikube delete` followed by `minikube start` ?

Comment: @thomas thx, I solved it with reinstall&upgrade minikube.

Answer (score 0):

**Resetting and restarting your cluster**

If you require a clean slate you can wipe out your local Minikube cluster and restart with issue an `minikube delete` and then `minikube start` commands:

```
➜  ~ minikube delete
  Deleting "minikube" in docker ...
  Deleting container "minikube" ...
  Removing /home/thomas/.minikube/machines/minikube ...
  Removed all traces of the "minikube" cluster.
```

[Synopsis](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/delete/)
Deletes a local Kubernetes cluster. This command deletes the VM, and removes all associated files.